# How to live with the frustration?

Tags: support

I face two sources of frustration on SE.

The one are the anonymous, unexplained downvotes. They aren't fun, and from experience, commenting to ask for an explanation just adds to the frustration, as you never get a reply.

The other are the accepted answers that you are convinced are wrong, though they keep getting votes. Claiming that they are wrong also has no effect as your post goes unnoticed or is not believed, an accepted answer often masking others.

[I am not claiming that I am always right to think an answer wrong - I may err too with significant probability. I am just saying that this is an uncomfortable situation.]

Have you found a way to cope with that ? (I am not looking for a way to counteract these situations, rather to accept misfortune :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moves to StackExchange meta

Comment: Why don't you just delete and repost? This is essentially what migration does.

Comment: Sorry - I tried to comment, got an error, so posted the "answer" below

Comment: I am doing that. But what is "migration" ?

Comment: I sometimes buy a bag of Skittles and eat one for each of those. Seems to work for me.

Comment: It is all about learning to accept the opinion of others.

Comment: Anyone who can't stand inexplicable antagonism and the fact that [someone on the internet is wrong](https://xkcd.com/386/) is probably not ready for life on the internet.

Comment: @2mkgz: I wish I could, SE's policy doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Herrmann: frustration exactly comes from that: people not sharing their opinion.

Comment: Ironic, since you yourself have contributed to wrong answers that you refused to fix even after your errors have been pointed out.

Answer (score 13):

Advice:  Ignore downvotes.  Don't let others determine your mood.

Don't ask "why the downvote?"

Dont come to Meta and complain about downvotes.

Instead, concentrate on the math!

Comment: Corollary (to the "ignore" advice).  Do no use terms like "idiot" or "coward" for those who downvote without explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you - I'm just starting out so I can't comment in meta. I just had a blanket down-vote of everything I'd posted up to now (member for 11 days). No comments and no explanation.

I believe there is a chance I may get the down-votes reversed by an automated procedure that runs overnight.

It's not very friendly - I have no idea what I've done to offend or how to correct my behaviour for the future.

Any suggestions gratefully received \ldots

Comment: I also can't understand why you got 7 downvotes in a short span of time.  I don't see anything wrong with your answers.

Comment: There's a non-zero chance that these downvotes will be automatically invalidated at about 03:00UTC. If this doesn't happen, flag one of your posts for moderator attention and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: I think these days, a huge part of downvotes come down to (1) revenge, and (2) downvotes as part of a larger initiative that's been going on for a while in which posts that don't satisfy the quality criteria of an in-crowd are encouraged to be discouraged by downvoting (per a link on the profile of the high priest of that religion at MSE, ideally with no comment). As revenge downvotes on *answers* are less likely, and you haven't down a thing to warrant it, it's probably a new acolyte of (2)'s religion trying to get their daily 40 downvotes. SO is even worse.

Comment: To be more clear: if I'm right, then those votes weren't on your posts, but on a question deemed unworthy and all who dare answering it.

Comment: @gnometorule: How does this initiative you describe lead to one user having 5 or more posts downvoted in 1 minute, if it wasn't this user's posts being targeted?  It doesn't seem plausible to me.

Comment: @gnometorule "revenge downvotes on answers are less likely": not really. I guess you think it's because of the rep cost associated to downvoting answers? I've been the target of serial downvoting several times in the past, these idiots don't stop at something like that. Besides, ip6 has only posted answers on the main site so far. I also agree with what Jonas Meyer said (and as usual, I'd be happy if people became less dramatic on meta: "religion"? "high priest"? Seriously... At least downvotes weren't compared to murder this time.)

Comment: @najib: A (secular) religion is acting according to a set of rules that are just as firm as the Ten Commandments for a Christian religious person, say. Adhering to these rules also defines typically some form of mission (clearly the case here). For those disagreeing, it's also about as reasonable, and comes from the same root: the sorry need to belong (hello chat room). You are obviously free to disagree, and declare this nonsense; I didn't expect my old comment to win a popularity contest. I missed the 1 minute timespan, so I agree that it's less likely here.

Comment: @gnometorule Would you mind pointing me to these rules and commandments? Or just tell me what they are? ("less likely"... What an understatement. It's okay to simply admit you were wrong. You tried to shoehorn your point in a completely unrelated situation without taking the time to check if anything matched, it failed. You might want to check the meaning of the word "secular", BTW.)

Comment: @Najib: As to a list, it's plainly [linked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question/252740#252740) in the likely profile. As stated there, it's not complete.

Comment: @Najib: As to secular religion, [here's](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_religion) a start. You are free to disagree, obviously, or claim that the situation doesn't match the definition linked. It wouldn't be hard to offer speculation on how this could still be related to what I claim, but it would be speculation only. As I don't "take things to chat," and don't want to deal with this obvious anger, I'll stop here.

Comment: @gnometorule It looks more like a list of types of questions that deserve to be downvoted than religious commandments, but I might be mistaken. I don't see anything about downvoting answers, which is what we're talking about. I'm curious in fact, do you disagree with downvoting in the cases listed? (And now I'm very confused, because I'm not angry and I don't think I appear to be either -- were you talking about me? You're an anonymous stranger, I don't care enough to be angry about this discussion...) (And after murder, now deletion is communism. Meta is wonderful.)